# Employer changed my title from what was agreed in offer letter

Tags: career-development

I am in the U.S. I joined this company 2 months ago (it's a large, global corp.), and now my boss says that my title is something else and not what I signed to in the offer letter. This "change" happened without informing me. I only found via the company's employee directory. Is this allowed?

I understand responsibilities and roles can change, but I am fairly certain it is something both parties have to agree to. I requested that my boss and I have a discussion about this, and I cc'd his boss on this as well.

My hope is to salvage things, and I don't want to jump ship so quickly. Any advice?

Edit to say: I checked the offer letter, and it does not have a clause about them being able to change the title at discretion.

Edit2: for context about the my job- it's within a business analysis unit that works on metrics of technology products. The title I agreed to had the word "manager" in it, and the one my boss is saying now doesn't. I expect this change to have an affect on my career development in the company.

Edit3: thanks for all the comments, all. My boss says I can use my previous title externally. I will do that, but I do feel blindsided that within the company I am not what I thought I was going to be when I joined. I am going to not care about that for now, and just focus on what I will be doing.

Comment: My current company has a very flat structure, and titles mean little. There's often a major disconnect between titles in the various org charts we use (company wiki, pingboard, etc). You should wait until you have your meeting before worrying.

Comment: Are you actually changing role, responsibility or salary based on this? Or is it just the title?

Comment: Is your title the only one that's been changed?

Comment: Mailing your boss an uber-boss requesting time for what they most probably perceive as a non issue is going to have far more effect on your career than not being called a manager.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to answer this question without knowing what the perceived downsides are.  People's job titles and descriptions can change around according to organisation changes without really affecting people's day to day work.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ seems like this would hurt a resume to have a lesser title given for a more complicated position.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this allowed?

In the US for at-will employees, companies can change titles at will as long as there isn't an employment contract with a contractually-specified title in it. It would be rare to find a contracted title outside of a union setting. (Note: an offer letter is not an employment contract.)

> I understand responsibilities and roles can change, but I am fairly
>   certain it is something both parties have to agree to.

Sorry, this is incorrect. Except in the cases I mentioned, your company doesn't need to gain your agreement to change your title.

Your recourse is to complain in hopes that the company gives you the title you want. And of course you can always leave.

You haven't mentioned *why* your boss changed your title. Perhaps you can point out that the reason was incorrect and appeal to better logic. But ultimately, the company can make this change if they want to.

I've worked at companies several times where they decided to change titles. In my case, entire groups had their titles changed. But a few individuals who held unique positions were really bothered, as their titles were changed to more generic terms.

One was bothered enough to leave. For all others, it wasn't important enough to do anything about and hasn't impacted anyone's careers as far as I can tell.

Comment: In some cases, titles ARE extremely important. In my experience working for a medical device manufacturer, I was incorrectly classed as a "technician" and not an "engineer". I was trained and qualified as an approvals engineer, meaning that I could sign off on validation plans and other docs, which is what I was doing. Had the FDA discovered that someone officially classed as a "technician" was signing these documents, hefty fines would have been levied and heads would have rolled.

Comment: Yes. I said "classified" but technician was also my job title

Comment: 4 jobs, 6 different job titles, same responsibilities across all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the title difference in the company directory was an oversight? It is good that you are having a chat with a your boss about it. You have good evidence to change your title since your offer letter says something different.

Frankly, titles don't matter in my company, so I change mine every week. Is it worth leaving over a title? I personally do not think so. Salary and responsibilities trump a title.

Comment: I agree, I am just waiting to talk to my boss. I wish there was a way to vet a company before you join them, there are a lot of unpleasant surprises here, and I wish there was a way to get "references" of an potential employer like they ask references of potential employees.

Comment: "I wish there was a way to vet a company before you join them" - Glassdoor.com.

Comment: @PeteCon glassdoor.com never has anything about any of the companies i approach in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: You can choose to take no action with no impact on your colleagues, future employers or clients/customers.

---

I've worked in a large organisation in the UK where job titles were:

- Misstated in some sources, e.g. saying that I am an Analyst instead of a Senior Analyst
- Have some strange formatting added to it, e.g. in my reference I was a Senior Analyst VBUS 1234, where the last parts were my cost centre and employee number
- Beefed up for the benefit of clients, e.g. I was once introduced as being the Senior Analysts Team Leader. That didn't make any sense, as I was the only Senior Analyst in the division anyway

In all of these cases, there was no action required. I didn't need to explain the 'change' in job title to colleagues, future employees or clients.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked for a company where the job titles meant anything.   In my time in the software industry, I've been called everything from "associate", to "programmer/analyst", to "systems engineer", to currently "software engineer 6".   I've had my title arbitrarily changed, I've been listed in the company directory with a different title than my HR forms say, and in one case I didn't even know what my title was.   I don't put much stock in titles.

I worked with someone several years ago who was very upset because he went from contract to hire at the company and they title they gave him was "Software Engineer" and he thought it should be "Sr Software Engineer".  The company had no leveling built into titles, if you were writing software, you were a software engineer.  He was miserable the entire time he was there over that issue and constantly brought it up.  Its really not worth that.

As far as I'm concerned, if I'm getting the pay, respect and assignments equal to my experience level I don't care what I'm called.

All of this assumes the title is something close to your job.   I would have an issue if I thought I was a software engineer and my title was Jr Accountant or Sr Civil Engineer.

Comment: What about your resume and references for future jobs? If you're applying for a senior position but your past employer says you were a junior it will hurt your chances.

Comment: your personal experience won't be relevant to every situation. DIfferent industries could handle this very differently, keep that in mind.